# Need Help understanding the HAVING clause as it relates to COUNT

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I am starting to learn sql and I am currently getting hung up on the 'having' clause when I use it in conjunction with COUNT. I have done a lot of research and my general understanding is that unlike where it waits to apply until any functions in the query have run.

This lead me to find the rather neat little function that allows me to find the closest locations to a given zip code by latitude and longitude. I started playing with this and used it to tie together three tables. One has a list of zip codes and their latitude longitudes while the other has a list of events and their zip codes and the last has a list of any special requirements for each event. The three event tables are tied to each other through an index. The latitude/longitude table is tied in via the zip code.

So for example:

```
  SELECT `EVENT_CAT`,
         `NAME`,
         (3959 * acos(cos(radians(44.643418)) * cos(radians(`Latitude`)) * cos(radians(`Longitude`) - radians(-73.121685) ) + sin( radians(44.643418)) * sin(radians( `Latitude`)))) AS distance 
    FROM DATA_ZipCodes 
    JOIN `EVENT_POST_General` ON ZIP_CODE = ZipCode 
    JOIN `DATA_EVENTCategories` ON EVENT_CAT = DATA_EVENTCategories.ID 
    JOIN `EVENT_POST_Filtering` ON EVENT_POST_General.EVENT_ID = EVENT_POST_Filtering.EVENT_ID 
   WHERE `REQUIRE_TICKET` = '0' 
  HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance
```

This works great and returns:

```
EVENT_CAT     NAME     DISTANCE
-------------------------------
1           CONCERT        1
1           CONCERT        1
1           CONCERT        1
2            GAMES         1
2            GAMES         2
3            DANCE         4
4           DINNER         4
5           MOVIES         4
```

The catch is I also want to be able to just query a count of how many of each category of events I have.

To this end I tried just encorporating a COUNT and GROUP BY

```
  SELECT COUNT(`EVENT_CAT`),
         `NAME`,
         (3959 * acos(cos(radians(44.643418)) * cos(radians(`Latitude`)) * cos(radians(`Longitude`) - radians(-73.121685) ) + sin( radians(44.643418)) * sin(radians( `Latitude`)))) AS distance 
    FROM DATA_ZipCodes 
    JOIN `EVENT_POST_General` ON ZIP_CODE = ZipCode 
    JOIN `DATA_EVENTCategories` ON EVENT_CAT = DATA_EVENTCategories.ID 
    JOIN `EVENT_POST_Filtering` ON EVENT_POST_General.EVENT_ID = EVENT_POST_Filtering.EVENT_ID 
   WHERE `REQUIRE_TICKET` = '0'
GROUP BY `EVENT_CAT` 
  HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance
```

When I do this however the response does not error but it also does not return anything. I am very baffled as to how to best do this. I tried moving the group by but that just caused errors.

*EDITED TO CORRECT THE GROUP_BY TO GROUP BY as that was a type when I was pasting it in here and is not in the original code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query a bit shorted:

```
SELECT COUNT(`EVENT_CAT`),`NAME`, ... as `distance`
FROM ...
WHERE `REQUIRE_TICKET` = '0'
GROUP_BY `EVENT_CAT` 
HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance
```

The `group by` clause (I think it should not have a `_` there, too) groups the result by different event_cat results, unifying the rest of the results. But:

- your query result does not even contain such a column.
- in each group you try to count how much different values of event_cat there are. There can only be one, if you would group by this.
- additionally, the other columns of the result are not depending only on the group-by column ... this does not work.

The `having` clause is used to filter the resulting groups after grouping. Since your distance is not unique in each group, this is not a good way to do it - put it instead in the `WHERE` clause, if you want to count how many events in 10 km distance are in each category. The problem is that you can't refer in the `WHERE` clause to fields only defined in the `SELECT` clause, so we need to put the formula into the WHERE clause.

Then count the different `name` values (or something else unique), not the `event_cat`.

```
SELECT `EVENT_CAT`, COUNT(`NAME`)
FROM ...
WHERE `REQUIRE_TICKET` = '0' AND ... < 10
GROUP_BY `EVENT_CAT`
```

Ordering by distance also is not possible, since the distance is not unique by category. Maybe ordering by count, or minimal distance, or such?

Comment: Ah, okay, I see what you mean. So when I use the GROUP BY I need to specify that column separately and make sure I count on a separately column. Out of curiosity, I assume I would tie myself in knots if I did "select count(event_cat),event_cat from... where... group by event_Cat"?

This helped a lot. I haven't worked in sql in a decade or so and am just getting back into it :) Apparently I forgot a lot...

Comment: Yes, counting on the group-by-column would only ever give 1. In your case it seems that `count(name)` is also not useful, since the name depends on the category - you would count some other information which would be unique for the event (like event-id).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
  SELECT dzc.name,
         COUNT(dzc.name),         
         (3959 * acos(cos(radians(44.643418)) * cos(radians(`Latitude`)) * cos(radians(`Longitude`) - radians(-73.121685) ) + sin( radians(44.643418)) * sin(radians( `Latitude`)))) AS distance 
    FROM DATA_ZipCodes dzc
    JOIN EVENT_POST_General epg ON epg.zip_code = dzc.zipcode
    JOIN DATA_EVENTCategories dec ON dec.id = dzc.event_cat
    JOIN EVENT_POST_Filtering epf ON epf.event_id = epg.event_id
   WHERE REQUIRE_TICKET = '0'
GROUP BY dzc.name
  HAVING distance < 10
ORDER BY distance
```

- you had a typo - there's no underscore in "GROUP BY"
- MySQL supports [hidden columns in the GROUP BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html), but few other databases do
- You [only need backticks in MySQL queries if you are escaping reserved/key words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)
- use table aliases -- makes the query more readable, and will give you more specific errors in the event a table gets changed

Comment: Ah, thank you for noticing that. I checked what I copied and pasted from and the _ in group by was actually a typo when I copied it into the questions - sorry about that *embarrassed grin*

Yeah, I always wondered on the backtiks. I was under the understanding that that was the case but as I wasn't aware of any downside to using them I just kinda got in the habit of including them.  

Thank you very much for the response, I will play with that a bit and see how I understand it. Much appreciated!

Comment: Yes, counting on the group-by-column would only ever give 1.
In your case it seems that `count(name)` is also not useful, since the name depends on the category - you would count some other information which would be unique for the event (like event-id).

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann: The example paints event_id and name as a 1:1 ratio, making counting by name or event_id moot.

Comment: @OMG: Hmm, looks like I commented on the wrong post ... my comment was targetet at Jasons comment to my answer, but then I had to login again, and copied it to the wrong answer. Sorry.

Comment: @OMG: Now reading your code: By the example output, I think the `NAME` in the original example was the name of the category, not the name of the zip code data. And `select dzc.name, COUNT(dzc.name) ... group by dzc.name` makes no sense independent of data structure.

Comment: Yes, the name was the category name. I apologize, I had difficulty giving a good example without including a ton of tables. I will try to make things clearer next time. Thank you again for all the help!